# How to limit HTTP/2 connections per IP?

Tags: nginx

From the [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_conn_module.html) of ngx_http_limit_conn_module,

> In HTTP/2 and SPDY, each concurrent request is considered a separate connection.

Is there a way limit HTTP/2 connections, not requests?

Also, doesn't this mean an attacker can establish any number of concurrent connections?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it precisely with NGINX (even with limit_conn), but you problably use ConfigServer Firewall or similar, right?

Firefox by default make 32 requests per connection (see for yourselft at: about:config -> network.http.pipelining), so I would set CT_LIMITS = "100", CT_INTERVAL = "20", CT_PORTS = "80,443". Why?

Simple, if a website usualy has 200 requests (guess by experience), you have ~8 connections (200/32 + 2 for safety) per visit. So, a single visitor can access more than 10 times the website and it will not be blocked, which is a very reasonable limit. More than that, it is considered DoS.

By the way, you can use http_limit_req_module with 45/s limit and 80s burst, it won't cause 503 errors and will block some small L7 floods, I can assure you that.

**Don't forget to use a real DDoS Protection, since softwares firewalls and web servers can't handle big DDoS attacks.**